# Clips: Matching (or not matching an empty string)

Tags: clips, expert-system

I'm try to translate a string piece by piece, so I know when the originating one is empty, then we're done. Question is, how will CLIPS know when there's nothing in the "input" string?

```
(defrule check-if-empty
    ?phase <- (phase CONVERT)
    (input "code here possibly")
    =>
    (retract ?phase ?input)
    (assert (phase PRINT))
    (return))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty string in CLIPS is "", so just replace "code here possibly" with "". There's also no need to place a return at the end of a rule unless you're using modules and want to end execution of rules in the module with the current focus.

```
(defrule check-if-empty
    ?phase <- (phase CONVERT)
    ?input <- (input "")
    =>
    (retract ?phase ?input)
    (assert (phase PRINT)))
```

Answer (score 0):

CLIPS has a build-in function called `str-length`. You have to check if the length is 0.

```
CLIPS> (defrule check-if-empty
    ?phase <- (phase CONVERT)
    ?input <- (input ?inputstr)
    (test (= (str-length ?inputstr) 0))
=>
    (retract ?phase ?input)
    (printout t "Empty string" crlf)
    (return)
)

CLIPS> (assert (phase CONVERT))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (assert (input "foo"))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (assert (input ""))
<Fact-3>
CLIPS> (run)
Empty string
```

You only have to change my `printout` to your `assert`.